# Liquidity Of Token In Pancake

Tags: blockchain, tokens, cryptoeconomics

i tried to connect my token via pancake just want to ask if i remove LP of my token so ppl can still trade or not?

And if someone bought my token will his money convert into LP?

And if yes? Then if i remove his money from LP and there is still my money in LP for trading can he still able to sell and buy? And there will be deduction in my LP?

Comment: You may try to rephrase your questions. I don't understand what you want to do. 

Since your question is specific to how uniswap / PancakeSwap work, you may have better answers on reddit.

Comment: If it works like Uniswap a token swap doesn't add liquidity. If you remove all liquidity by burning LP tokens then nobody will be able to trade. If you have more token you can always swap them for ether.